# Alternating sum $1-4+9-16+\cdots$

Tags: complex-analysis, summation

What would be a reduced form of $1-4+9-16+\dots+(2n-1)^2$
I don't mean the form $$\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}(-1)^{k}k^2$$
I mean a way to make the sum being dependent only on n.

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$

Comment: thats not the same sum

Comment: I believe you want to evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}(-1)^{k+1}k^2$, not $\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}(-1)^{k}(1^2+2^2+3^2+.....+k^2)$, isn't it? If so, you should correct your question.

Comment: yeah, you are right, I copied another one i think

Comment: @LorianaMesia It was supposed to be a *hint*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S_1=\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1}(-1)^{i+1}i^2=1-4+9-16+...+(2n-1)^2$

We know that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, so let $S_{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1}i^2=1+4+9+...+(2n-1)^2.$

Then $$S_{1}+S_{2}=2+18+...+2(2n-1)^2=$$
$$=2(1+3^2+...+(2n-1)^2)=2\sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i-1)^2=8\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2-8\sum_{i=1}^{n}i+2\sum_{i=1}^{n}1$$
$$=\frac{4n(n+1)(2n+1)}{3}-4n(n+1)+2n$$

Thus $$S_{1}=\frac{4n(n+1)(2n+1)}{3}-4n(n+1)+2n-\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1}i^2$$
$$=\frac{4n(n+1)(2n+1)}{3}-4n(n+1)+2n-\frac{2n(2n-1)(4n-1)}{6}$$
$$=n(2n-1)$$

[As mentioned by paw88789, you are ending the sum on a positive term]

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}(-1)^{k}k^2=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{2k-1}(2k-1)^2+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{2k}(2k)^2$$

then use

- $\sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$
- $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: [I am assuming that you are always ending the sum on a positive term--that's what your post seems to indicate.]

Look at the first few terms:

$n=1$:  $1$

$n=2$: $1-4+9=6$

$n=3$:  $1-4+9-16+25=15$

$\vdots$

Each value factors in a nice way, and perhaps the pattern continues; and you can verify the pattern by induction.

Comment: 1−4+9−16+25=15 $\rightarrow$ 1−4+9−16+25=15. It doesn't allow me to edit less than 6 characters.

Comment: @BillyJoe: Thank you for the correction. I edited it in.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a sign error.  The sum you want is $$\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}(-1)^{k+1}k^2$$  Then
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}(-1)^{k+1}k^2=\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}k^2-2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(2k)^2$$ and you can apply the known formula for the sum of the first $n$ squares.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it backwards, e.g.
$$(7^2 - 6^2) + (5^2 - 4^2) + (3^2 - 2^2) + (1^2 - 0^2) = 13 + 9 + 5 + 1 = 4(3 + 2 + 1 + 0) + 4.$$
If the highest term (e.g. $7$) is $2n - 1$ this will give
$$4((n-1) + (n-2) + \cdots + 0) + n = 2n(n-1) + n = n(2n - 1).$$